# Azure pipeline not applying label to Docker build container

Tags: azure, docker, testing, pipeline, xunit

As the title says, I am trying to apply a label to my docker container so I can then reference said container in a further step in my pipeline.  My end result that I am going for is to be able to copy my test results out of the container and publish and display those results.

**azure-pipeline.yml**

```
# Docker
# Build a Docker image
# https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/devops/pipelines/languages/docker

trigger:
- main
- develop

resources:
- repo: self

variables:
  tag: '$(Build.BuildId)'

stages:
- stage: Build
  displayName: Build image
  jobs:
  - job: Build
    displayName: Build
    pool:
      name: default
    steps:
    - task: Docker@2
      displayName: Build an image
      inputs:
        command: build
        arguments: '--build-arg BuildId=$(Build.BuildId)'
        dockerfile: '$(Build.SourcesDirectory)/Dockerfile'
        tags: |
          $(tag)
    - powershell: |
        $id=docker images --filter "label=test=$(Build.BuildId)" -q | Select-Object -First 1
        docker create --name testcontainer $id
        docker cp testcontainer:/testresults ./testresults
        docker rm testcontainer
      displayName: 'Copy test results'
    - task: PublishTestResults@2
      displayName: 'Publish test results'
      inputs:
        testResultsFormat: 'xUnit'
        testResultsFiles: '**/*.trx'
        searchFolder: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/testresults'
```

**Dockerfile**

```
#See https://aka.ms/containerfastmode to understand how Visual Studio uses this Dockerfile to build your images for faster debugging.

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:6.0-bullseye-slim-amd64 AS base
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 80

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:6.0-bullseye-slim-amd64 AS build
WORKDIR /src
COPY ["Forecast/Forecast.csproj", "Forecast/"]
WORKDIR "/src/Forecast"
RUN dotnet restore "Forecast.csproj"
COPY Forecast/ .
RUN dotnet build "Forecast.csproj" -c Release -o /app/build

FROM build AS publish
WORKDIR /src
RUN dotnet publish "Forecast/Forecast.csproj" --no-restore -c Release -o /app/publish

FROM build as test
ARG BuildId
LABEL test=${BuildId}
WORKDIR /src
COPY ["ForecastXUnitTest/ForecastXUnitTest.csproj", "ForecastXUnitTest/"]
WORKDIR "/src/ForecastXUnitTest"

RUN dotnet restore "ForecastXUnitTest.csproj"
COPY ForecastXUnitTest/ .
RUN dotnet build "ForecastXUnitTest.csproj" -c Release -o /app
RUN dotnet test -c Release --results-directory /testresults --logger "trx;LogFileName=test_results.trx" "ForecastXUnitTest.csproj"

FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app/publish .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "Forecast.dll"]
```

I can see that the label hasn't been applied upon inspection of the build steps.  The `powershell` step specifically the line `docker create --name testcontainer $id` the variable `$id` is empty and is telling me that the label is never applied so I'm not able to go any further.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up figuring out where my issue lay.  I end up with cache'd ephemeral container images.  With these in place Docker no longer runs those steps so along the way I added in the steps but with what had preceded in builds I wasn't getting anything from subsequent calls.

On top of this I had been referring to a previous image with the directive `FROM` that was preventing my directory from being found.